# Question.objects.all() isn't returning what's intended

Tags: python, django

Hi so I'm coding along to Django's official guide however I'm having a bit of trouble with my code.

I'm using the Python shell and I'm running the `Question.objects.all()` command and it returns with the following:

`<QuerySet [<Question: Question object (1)>, <Question: Question object (2)>]>`

The answer I'm looking for is `<QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>`

Comment: You need to override model's `__str__` method

Comment: Do I do that in my python shell or models.py file? Sorry for what may sound like a silly question pretty new to writing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer I'm looking for is `<QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>`

If your database has two `Question` objects, then `Question.objects.all()` is never going to return just one result.  (Did you really mean you wanted *only one* result?)

By default, when a model object is printed, it will print the model primary key.  If you want different behavior, then as Avinash commented, you need to override the `__str__` method in the Question class, like so:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    # fields go here

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text # or whatever field(s) you want
```

Comment: Thanks both! so if I wanted just one result what would the command look like?

Comment: `Question.objects.filter(text='I want this text')`

Answer (score 0):

when you define your model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key =True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.question
```

so you need to write an **str** function like this so that when you run a query the objects will appear as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one result you can also use get:

```
Question.objects.get(text='I want this text')
```

Note that this will raise an error if there are multiple entries that match this criteria. This is why get is typically used with id or some other unique entry.

Answer (score 0):

> <QuerySet [<Question: Question object (1)>, <Question: Question object
> (2)>]>
>
> The answer I'm looking for is <QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>

Save these changes and start a new Python interactive shell by running python manage.py shell again: